# JVM memory full on my Ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, support

`Dspace` is installed on my Ubuntu server. It's JVM memory is very low. Any way to increase the JVM memory?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu~~ First: we need some more info... Can you include some system info? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** you can increase the size for your needs when starting:

```
java -Xms<size>
```

means memory.

and this command can be used...

java -Xmx 
means the **max** size.

Remember to put m or mb after the number etc: 1024**mb** **or else the poor little memory thought you meant bytes....

And to mark me as answered click that tick over there.

:)
EDIT: You want to **MAX** the memory PERMANENTLY? (well unless if you undo it)
Use these:

```
-XX:PermSize<size>
```

and this for **MAX**

```
XX:MaxPermSize<size>
```

For ubuntu, remove XX and replace it with java

Comment: How to find the current Xmx size and Xms size.. i can only find JVM memory By using a webtool. Current Jvm Memmory is only 128Mb

Comment: java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version

Comment: see if that will help

Comment: I am trying all the above commands . all are not working

Comment: java -XshowSettings:vm will show you the max heap size